# Where Clause with IN operator for Fillo Excel API Query

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver

I have tried using IN operator in where clause of the Query to fetch the records from excel file using fillo. Seems IN operator making to ignore that condition itself and provides results by ignoring that condition.

```
Select * from Test_Flow where Type = 'Regression' and SubGroup IN ('Textbox')
```

No. of record set fetched : 14

Expected Result: Should be 1 Record set. But it fetches all records irrespective of the condition

```
Select * from Test_Flow where Type = 'Regression' and SubGroup = 'Textbox'
```

No. of record set fetched : 1

```
Select * from Test_Flow  where Type = 'Regression' and (SubGroup = 'Textbox' OR SubGroup = 'Button')
```

No. of record set fetched : 14

Expected Result: No. of record set fetched should be 2

Could anyone confirm is this an issue with Fillo?